# How to annotate same text for different fields in Portia?

Tags: python, annotations, portia, scrapinghub

I want to annotate the content which has three lines in three individual fields which is in single html tag.
I tried with partial annotation method. But some content has only 2 lines(partial annotation is not working in this scenario)
How Can I annotate in the content?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this at the moment but an update in the next month will make this possible.

For now you can [create a pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#writing-your-own-item-pipeline) for your spider where you can split the data into as many fields as you would like